# What's the same method in CoreBluetooth of onCharacteristicChanged of Android?

Tags: android, ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a demo of Android BLE application. After it runs `mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mCharacteristic)`, if the data changes, `onCharacteristicChanged` of `BluetoothGattCallback` will be called.

But I want to write an iOS version of it. I send data as below:

```
let character = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: cuivienenCharacterUUID, properties: .Write, value: nil, permissions: [.Readable, .Writeable])
test_peripheral.writeValue(NSData(bytes: data, length: data.count), forCharacteristic: character, type: .WithResponse)
test_peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: character)
```

I think I can also receive data just like Android in method like `func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?)`. But nothing happened! Why can't I get any response from BLE device? Am I using the wrong method?

I can just make sure UUID is correct, will different settings in properties and permissions affect the result?

Comment: A write with response request will result in a call to the `didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error` CBPeripheralDelegate method. Have you implemented this?

Comment: @Paulw11 But onCharacteristicChanged will bring data back

Comment: You should maybe check if the characteristic you are trying to receive data from has to be set as **notify**, which you are doing now, and **indicate**, which could be a possible solution to your problem. They are quite the same, but indicate requires acknowledgements after having received data (You don't have to do that manually)